# キーの同時押しでプログラムを終了したい

Tags: autohotkey

autohotkeyでのプログラミングについての質問です。

プログラムの終了は `key_exit := "End"` のような簡単なコードで書いているのですが、EndキーとF12キーの同時押しでこのコマンドを実行したい時、以下の「」の中にはどのような記述をすれば良いでしょうか。

```
key_exit := 「 」
```

Comment: その書き方はおそらくAutoHotKeyの基本的な機能では無く、貴方の作ったプログラム内での独自の使い方だと思われるので、その辺を他の人が区別できる程度にはプログラムの全貌を提示する必要があると思われます。こんな形のプログラムではありませんか？ [05-13-2020 #13](https://www.mpgh.net/forum/showthread.php?t=1498719&p=14805984&viewfull=1#post14805984)

Comment: [AutoHotkeyJpサイト](https://sites.google.com/site/autohotkeyjp/reference/Hotkeys) にはコンビネーションキーの記述方法も記載されていますが、質問者さんが開示されているコードはkunifさんも書かれているように独自の処理のように見えます。動いていなくてもかまいませんので、処理の前後を含めた現時点でのコードを追記していただいた方がアドバイスが集まりやすいと思います。